# How do I define unary minus for a custom type in F#?

Tags: f#

How do I define `-x` for a custom type in F#?

This will complain that it expects a tuple:

```ml
type Vector2<'T> = 
  | Vector2 of 'T * 'T
  with
    static member inline (-) (Vector2 (x, y)) =
      Vector2 (-x, -y)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `~` char to the operator definition.

```
static member inline (~-) (Vector2 (x, y)) = Vector2 (-x, -y)
```

That will tell the compiler that is a unary operator.